# Help me find the problem with my solution to Project Euler #12 in Haskell

Tags: algorithm, haskell, math

I'm a total newbie to Haskell, and programming in general, but I'm trying to work through some Project Euler problems because I do like problem solving.  However, I have a problem with [problem #12](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=12).

I devised a solution I thought would work, but alas, it does not.

Can you help me by opening my eyes to the problem with my code, 
and maybe push me in the right direction towards fixing it?  Thank you.

Here is the code:

```
triangleNumber = scanl1 (+) [1..]

factors n = [x | x <- [1..n], n `mod` x == 0]

numFactors = length . factors

eulerTwelve = find ((>500) . numFactors) triangleNumber
```

Thank you very much!  :)

Comment: Looks good to me.  What's the specific problem you are having?

Comment: its moving unbelievably slowly

Comment: And the whole point about project Euler is that you can do most problems using brute force, or you can do them intelligently using an artful to avoid the brute force. If your code is slow, then are you just using the brute force approach? Think about the problem before you write the brute force code. In the case of PE 12, this is tractable using even brute force if you do so in a reasonable way. (That is true of most small numbered PE problems.) There is a way to improve on that solution though. Think about what is the sum of the numbers 1 through n.

Answer (score 3):

The Project Euler questions are designed so that it's a bad idea to try solve them by "brute force", that is, by programming the obvious search and just leaving it to run. (Some of the earlier questions can be solved like that, but it's a good idea not to exploit that, but to use them as practice.) Instead, you have to think about the mathematical content of the question so as to make the computer search tractable.

I don't want to give away too much, but here are some hints:

- There's a formula for the *n*th triangular number. Find it, so you don't have to compute it by summation.
- Given this formula for the *n*th triangular number, what numbers can possibly be its divisors?
- Given what you know about these divisors, what's an easy way to figure out how many of them are there? (Without having to enumerate them.)

Comment: The closed form of the _n_ th triangle number is good to know, but it won't make this more efficient, since you still have to inspect all the triangle numbers in order until you find the correct one. In fact I would guess the `scanl1 (+)` method is slightly _more_ efficient given this fact.

Comment: @pelotom: I agree that *if* you had to compute all the triangle numbers then repeated summation would be the best way to do it. But what makes you think you have to compute *any* triangle numbers? (Apart from the one that you need for the answer.)

Comment: @Gareth: fair point, I am making that assumption. Do you have a solution which doesn't require examining each triangle number in order?

Comment: @pelotom That would be telling! :)

Comment: @Gareth: I am very intrigued... please enlighten me! And if you're just talking about reducing the complexity by a constant factor (for instance, by starting the search at 1000), I don't think that counts ;)

Comment: @pelotom: See my second and third hints above.

Answer (score 2):

I copied it and what it threw me was an error that find couldn't be found. That is because you need to import the module List where find is in:

```
import Data.List
```

By the way, you should optimize your factors function.

Comment: About the factors optimization: To solve some of the later PE problems, it is important that you build up a toolbox of functions for solving common tasks. Factorization of integers happen to be one of these things, but as you slowly work over problems you will find there are more things than just this. So when you start, use the simple solution, but keep in mind to come back and optimize it further later on.

Comment: Yeah, I did import Data.List forgot to include that in the post though, however, the problem I was experiencing wasn't any sort of explicit error but rather extreme slowness in my computer producing the answer,

Comment: I do think that it may be the factors function that's slowing it though so I will try to optimize that, thank you

Answer (score 1):

I assume the problem you're alluding to is that `eulerTwelve` takes way too long to terminate; your code is correct, it's just inefficient. The bottleneck is your `factors` function, which is trying every number between 1 and `n` to see if it's a divisor of `n`. Here's a faster way to find the divisors of a number, using [efficient prime factorization](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/primes/0.2.0.0/doc/html/Data-Numbers-Primes.html) and [a nifty implementation of the power set](http://community.livejournal.com/evan_tech/220036.html):

```
import Data.Numbers.Primes (primeFactors)

powerSet = filterM (const [True, False])

factors = map product . nub . powerSet . primeFactors
```

Even this is pretty inefficient; you can instead calculate `numFactors` directly from `primeFactors` like so:

```
numFactors = product . map ((+1) . length) . group . primeFactors
```

When I replace your `numFactors` with this one I obtain the result instantly.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC when checking for factors you don't need to test every integer between 1 and n - only the numbers between 1 and n^0.5 (squareroot of n), since at this number you will already have obtained all the factors available.

Comment: Only (approximately) half of them, and the prime factorization is more efficient anyway.